# Recommended approach to fatal technical errors during Kafka processing in a partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I had a question about the recommended approach to deal with fatal technical errors during Kafka streaming.

Scenario:

1. All messages of a business transaction are in one partition
2. Processing a message repeatedly causes exceptions in the application (not related to Kafka)
3. We cannot skip over a message as order is important (all messages of one transaction need to be processed together)
4. Kafka automatically assigns partitions to the consumer (no manual assignment)

Given these constraints,

1. If I stop the consumer, then the partition with the problem messages merely gets assigned to a different consumer, and the same problem repeats.
2. If I stop the entire consumer group, I'm delaying processing of **all partitions**, whereas if they were still processing, I could have processed other non problematic transactions.

What would be the recommended approach to such a situation ?
Also, is it possible to shutdown the entire consumer group somehow without having a application synchronization mechanism (for multi node consumer group) ?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka streams has exactly once semantics i.e. a message will be processed only once, even in case of failure. You just need to set `processing.guarantee=exactly_once` in your streams configuration. For more refer to the [following article](http://web.archive.org/https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-once-kafka-streams/).

As for the order of messages, they are consumed in the order they are produced. Since the keys for all the messages in a transaction will be same, they land in the same partition (atleast by default partitioning logic).

You can also make use of *intermediate topics* to store your intermediate state using `KStream.through()` method.

Apart from this, you have state stores (*local* (only partitions assigned to that instance) and *global* (all partitions)) to store your state.
If any one of the consumer dies and is redeployed somewhere else (in another node where store data is not there), then the state store will be built from Kafka changelog.